# Externalizing links in servlets to a constant

Tags: java, servlets

I have lots of servlets that redirects through

```
response.sendRedirect(URL)
```

And URL has a absolute path starting with `http://localhost:8080`.
Well, I need to change URL so I make this server online, but don't want to change
all instances of URL in all servlets.

Needed to know if there's a way to externalize this constant neatly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) file or make use of *context parameters* in your `web.xml`. Using *properties* is preferred if you would like to later provide language translations for your web application. If there are only a few constants that need to be externalised like the server url and admin email etc. *context parameters* is an equally good choice.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>server-hostname</param-name>
  <param-value>http://www.domain.com/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You can access this parameter globally from any Servlet as

```
response.sendRedirect(
         getServletContext().getInitParameter("server-hostname") + "page.php"));
```